# Firebase Mobile App Tracking - Which libraries to use?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

may I ask you:
We would like to implement mobile app tracking in Google Analytics in both Android and iOS apps. We are using a standard guide with Firebase analytics and Google Tag Manager.

There is a list of libraries available at the Firebase website:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Which of them do we need to implement, if we want to track all standard things in Google Analytics, like screenviews, events.

com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.1          Analytics

com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.1      Realtime Database

com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.2.1       Storage

com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.2.1         Crash Reporting

com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.1          Authentication

com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1              Cloud Messaging and Notifications

com.google.firebase:firebase-config:10.2.1       Remote Config

com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:10.2.1      Invites and Dynamic Links

com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.1            AdMob

com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:10.2.1          App Indexing

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Analytics and Google Analytics are two difference services.

If you want to implement Firebase Analytics then you add:

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.x.x
```

If you want to implement Google Analytics then you have to add:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.x.x'
```

For complete installation guide and latest version follow official guidelines 
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/

Comment: Hi Sharj, thank you for your answer. We are implementing GA via Firebase Analytics, because it is a recommended method from Google: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2587086?hl=en   But I guess I can use your answer that it is only enough to implement the core library. Thank you very much, very appreciated

Comment: @user3702392 you are right. In that case, you just have to add `firebase-core` library. But if you connect Firebase to GA, it will show you the same information in GA that it already shows in Firebase Analytics. If you implement GA you can get more information such as real-time user engagement.